# 2D Coordinate rotation - image distorted

Tags: math, rotation, coordinates, trigonometry, distortion

I have an arrow, represented as X,Y points, that I want to rotate 25 degrees.  My arrow rotates, but it no longer looks good.  The angles are no longer 90 degrees where they should be.  The points:

```
-85.0,0.0
-25.0,50.0
-25.0,15.0
85.0,15.0
85.0,-15.0
-25.0,-15.0
-25.0,-50.0
-85.0,0.0
```

This makes an image [that looks like this](http://itools.subhashbose.com/grapher/index.php?x%5B%5D=-85&y%5B%5D=0&x%5B%5D=-25&y%5B%5D=50&x%5B%5D=-25&y%5B%5D=15&x%5B%5D=85&y%5B%5D=15&x%5B%5D=85&y%5B%5D=-15&x%5B%5D=-25&y%5B%5D=-15&x%5B%5D=-25&y%5B%5D=-50&x%5B%5D=-85&y%5B%5D=0&submit=Plot%20Graph&w=800&h=800&n=&dtsz=Auto&title=Arrow,%20no%20rotation&shax=on&xlbl=&axx=on&aspx=Auto&ylbl=&axy=on&aspy=Auto&sh_lbl_hv=on&nfurl=on&nStrip=on).

Here is my (PHP) code to rotate the points:

```
$pts = array(
    array( -85, 0 ),
    array( -25, 50 ),
    array( -25, 15 ),
    array( 85, 15 ),
    array( 85, -15 ),
    array( -25, -15 ),
    array( -25, -50 ),
    array( -85, 0 ),
);

$rotate = deg2rad( 25 );
$sin = sin( $rotate );
$cos = cos( $rotate );

foreach( $pts as $xy ) {
    list( $x, $y ) = $xy;

    // Rotate
    $x2 = ( $x * $cos ) - ( $y * $sin );
    $y2 = ( $x * $sin ) + ( $y * $cos );

    printf( "%0.3f, %0.3f\n", $x2, $y2 );
}
```

Output:

```
-77.036, -35.923
-43.789, 34.750
-28.997, 3.029
70.697, 49.517
83.375, 22.328
-16.318, -24.160
-1.527, -55.881
-77.036, -35.923
```

The resulting image [no longer looks good](http://itools.subhashbose.com/grapher/index.php?x%5B%5D=-77.036161898115&y%5B%5D=-35.922552247959&x%5B%5D=-43.788607762951&y%5B%5D=34.749932808315&x%5B%5D=-28.996968602027&y%5B%5D=3.0291602620323&x%5B%5D=70.696887972005&y%5B%5D=49.517169053509&x%5B%5D=83.375435824226&y%5B%5D=22.32793544241&x%5B%5D=-16.318420749806&y%5B%5D=-24.160073349067&x%5B%5D=-1.5267815888813&y%5B%5D=-55.88084589535&x%5B%5D=-77.036161898115&y%5B%5D=-35.922552247959&submit=Plot%20Graph&w=800&h=800&n=&dtsz=Auto&title=Arrow,%20rotated%2025%20degrees&shax=on&xlbl=&axx=on&aspx=Auto&ylbl=&axy=on&aspy=Auto&sh_lbl_hv=on&nfurl=on&nStrip=on).

What am I doing wrong in my math?  I'd like it to still have 90 degree corners where it should, etc.

Thank you!
Seth

EDIT:  The rest of this exercise is that I'm translating the points to latitude/longitude coordinates for displaying in Google Earth.  Translation code:

```
$x2 = ( $x2 * $scale ) + $latref;
$y2 = ( $y2 * $scale ) + $lonref;
```

Is my "real" problem (as @joel-in-go points out), the physical distance between degrees of latitude and longitude not equal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your maths - the scales on the X and Y coordinate axes in your graph are not the same :)

Comment: Ah!  I just adjusted it so it's a square image and it came out correct!  Thank you!  Is there any way to do this so I can still have a rectangular arrow?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... what is a rectangular arrow?

Comment: The point is, the scale (units per pixel, here) must be the same on the X and Y axes for images not to be distorted. I don't know how to tell your graphing program to do this, I'm afraid.

Comment: I shrunk the length of the arrow down, so the maximum points on the X and Y are now both a maximum of 100 points.  [Looks right](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tz2d8jldf3kabxm/arrow-square.png).  I'd like the shaft of the arrow to be longer, however.  Is there anything I can do in my math to compensate?

Comment: Sure - change the size of the graph :) I tried your first arrow with a graph area of 1200 x 800, and it looks about right.

Comment: The rest of the exercise is that I'm translating the points to latitude/longitude points (by scaling and adding an offset), then plotting on Google Earth.  So any compensation would have to be in the math.  I'll edit my question above.

Comment: YAY!  I added a small scaling factor just to the Y side to make it appear square.  Now the rotate works great.  THANK YOU @joel-in-go!